# При использовании связи @OneToMany не сохраняется внешний ключ

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

У меня есть два `persistance`-класса, которые надо сохранять в таблицах:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "organization")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}, ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Organization extends BlockchainEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "msp")
    @JsonProperty("msp")
    private String msp;

    @Column(name = "name")
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "emails")
    @JsonProperty("emails")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "organization", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<OrganizationEmail> emails;
```

и второй класс:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "organization_email")
public class OrganizationEmail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "organization_msp", referencedColumnName = "msp", nullable = false)
    private Organization organization;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private EmailType type;
    private String email;
```

При запросе информации об организации должны извлекаться все принадлежащие ей емейлы. И при добавлении новой организации должны добавлятся ее емейлы в отдельную таблицу.

Проблема в том, что при создании новой организации через апи в таблице `organization_email` заполняются все поля емейла, кроме внешнего ключа, который связывает эти две таблицы. Поэтому при запросе информации об организации емейлы не извлекаются.

Как сделать так, чтобы внешний ключ сохранялся?

Более полные исходники:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import ru.xxx.flex.core.control.proto.OrganizationInfo;
import ru.xxx.flex.core.db.BlockchainEntity;
import ru.xxx.flex.core.enums.OrganizationType;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Entity
@Table(name = "organization")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}, ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Organization extends BlockchainEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "msp")
    @JsonProperty("msp")
    private String msp;

    @Column(name = "name")
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "role")
    @JsonProperty("type")
    private OrganizationType type;

    @Column(name = "channel")
    @JsonProperty("channelId")
    private String channelId;

    @Column(name = "inn")
    @JsonProperty("individualTaxNumber")
    private String individualTaxNumber;

    @Column(name = "kpp")
    @JsonProperty("codeOfReasonRegistration")
    private String codeOfReasonRegistration;

    @Column(name = "bik")
    @JsonProperty("bankIdentificationCode")
    private String bankIdentificationCode;

    @Column(name = "operating_account_number")
    @JsonProperty("operatingAccountNumber")
    private String operatingAccountNumber;

    @Column(name = "correspondent_account_number")
    @JsonProperty("correspondentAccountNumber")
    private String correspondentAccountNumber;

    @Column(name = "legal_address")
    @JsonProperty("legalAddress")
    private String legalAddress;

    @Column(name = "bank_name")
    @JsonProperty("bankName")
    private String bankName;

    @Column(name = "full_name")
    @JsonProperty("fullName")
    private String fullName;

    @Column(name = "legal_form")
    @JsonProperty("legalForm")
    private String legalForm;

    @Column(name = "okpo")
    @JsonProperty("businessAndOrganizationClassificationCode")
    private String businessAndOrganizationClassificationCode;

    @Column(name = "ogrn")
    @JsonProperty("primaryStateRegistrationNumber")
    private String primaryStateRegistrationNumber;

    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    @JsonProperty("phoneNumber")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name = "emails")
    @JsonProperty("emails")
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<OrganizationEmail> emails;

    public Organization() {
    }

    public Organization(String msp, String name, OrganizationType type, String channelId) {
        this.msp = msp;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.channelId = channelId;
    }

    public Organization(OrganizationInfo oi) {
        this.msp = oi.getMSP();
        this.name = oi.getName();
        this.type = oi.getRole();
        this.individualTaxNumber = oi.getIndividualTaxNumber();
        this.codeOfReasonRegistration = oi.getCodeOfReasonRegistration();
        this.bankIdentificationCode = oi.getBankIdentificationCode();
        this.operatingAccountNumber = oi.getOperatingAccountNumber();
        this.correspondentAccountNumber = oi.getCorrespondentAccountNumber();
        this.legalAddress = oi.getLegalAddress();
        this.bankName = oi.getBankName();
        this.fullName = oi.getFullName();
        this.legalForm = oi.getLegalForm();
        this.businessAndOrganizationClassificationCode = oi.getBusinessAndOrganizationClassificationCode();
        this.primaryStateRegistrationNumber = oi.getPrimaryStateRegistrationNumber();
        this.phoneNumber = oi.getPhoneNumber();
        this.emails = oi.getEmailsList().stream()
                .map(mail -> new OrganizationEmail(mail))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public String getMsp() {
        return msp;
    }

    public void setMsp(String msp) {
        this.msp = msp;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public OrganizationType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(OrganizationType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getChannelId() {
        return channelId;
    }

    public void setChannelId(String channelId) {
        this.channelId = channelId;
    }

    public String getIndividualTaxNumber() {
        return individualTaxNumber;
    }

    public void setIndividualTaxNumber(String individualTaxNumber) {
        this.individualTaxNumber = individualTaxNumber;
    }

    public String getCodeOfReasonRegistration() {
        return codeOfReasonRegistration;
    }

    public void setCodeOfReasonRegistration(String codeOfReasonRegistration) {
        this.codeOfReasonRegistration = codeOfReasonRegistration;
    }

    public String getBankIdentificationCode() {
        return bankIdentificationCode;
    }

    public void setBankIdentificationCode(String bankIdentificationCode) {
        this.bankIdentificationCode = bankIdentificationCode;
    }

    public String getOperatingAccountNumber() {
        return operatingAccountNumber;
    }

    public void setOperatingAccountNumber(String operatingAccountNumber) {
        this.operatingAccountNumber = operatingAccountNumber;
    }

    public String getCorrespondentAccountNumber() {
        return correspondentAccountNumber;
    }

    public void setCorrespondentAccountNumber(String correspondentAccountNumber) {
        this.correspondentAccountNumber = correspondentAccountNumber;
    }

    public String getLegalAddress() {
        return legalAddress;
    }

    public void setLegalAddress(String legalAddress) {
        this.legalAddress = legalAddress;
    }

    public String getBankName() {
        return bankName;
    }

    public void setBankName(String bankName) {
        this.bankName = bankName;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getLegalForm() {
        return legalForm;
    }

    public void setLegalForm(String legalForm) {
        this.legalForm = legalForm;
    }

    public String getBusinessAndOrganizationClassificationCode() {
        return businessAndOrganizationClassificationCode;
    }

    public void setBusinessAndOrganizationClassificationCode(String businessAndOrganizationClassificationCode) {
        this.businessAndOrganizationClassificationCode = businessAndOrganizationClassificationCode;
    }

    public String getPrimaryStateRegistrationNumber() {
        return primaryStateRegistrationNumber;
    }

    public void setPrimaryStateRegistrationNumber(String primaryStateRegistrationNumber) {
        this.primaryStateRegistrationNumber = primaryStateRegistrationNumber;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public List<OrganizationEmail> getEmails() {
        return emails;
    }

    public void setEmails(List<OrganizationEmail> emails) {
        this.emails = emails;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Organization{" +
                "msp='" + msp + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", type=" + type +
                ", channelId='" + channelId + '\'' +
                ", individualTaxNumber='" + individualTaxNumber + '\'' +
                ", codeOfReasonRegistration='" + codeOfReasonRegistration + '\'' +
                ", bankIdentificationCode='" + bankIdentificationCode + '\'' +
                ", operatingAccountNumber='" + operatingAccountNumber + '\'' +
                ", correspondentAccountNumber='" + correspondentAccountNumber + '\'' +
                ", legalAddress='" + legalAddress + '\'' +
                ", bankName='" + bankName + '\'' +
                ", fullName='" + fullName + '\'' +
                ", legalForm='" + legalForm + '\'' +
                ", businessAndOrganizationClassificationCode='" + businessAndOrganizationClassificationCode + '\'' +
                ", primaryStateRegistrationNumber='" + primaryStateRegistrationNumber + '\'' +
                ", phoneNumber='" + phoneNumber + '\'' +
                ", emails=" + emails +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Второй:

```
import ru.xxx.flex.core.control.proto.EmailType;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "organization_email")
public class OrganizationEmail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "organization_msp", referencedColumnName = "msp", nullable = false)
    private Organization organization;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private EmailType type;
    private String email;

    public OrganizationEmail() {}

    public OrganizationEmail(EmailType type, String email) {
        this.type = type;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public OrganizationEmail(ru.xxx.flex.core.control.proto.OrganizationEmail email) {
        this.email = email.getEmail();
        this.type = email.getType();
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public EmailType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(EmailType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Organization getOrganization() {
        return organization;
    }

    public void setOrganization(Organization organization) {
        this.organization = organization;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OrganizationEmail{" +
                "type=" + type +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

По GraphQL-запросу я сохраняю объект Organization в репозиторий:

```
@Repository
public interface OrganizationRepository extends JpaRepository<Organization, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Organization> {
    @Query(nativeQuery = true,
            value = "select * from organization " +
                    "where role = ?1",
            countQuery = "select count(*) from organization " +
                    "where role = ?1")
    Set<Organization> findAllByRole(OrganizationType role);
}
```

Запись появляется в таблице `organization` и `organization_email`, но при этом внешний ключ не устанавливается:

```
 id | organization_msp |  type  |     email      
----+------------------+--------+----------------
 19 |                  | CLAIMS | claims@mail.ru
 22 |                  | CLAIMS | claims@mail.ru
 25 |                  | CLAIMS | claims@mail.ru
 28 |                  | CLAIMS | claims@mail.ru
 31 |                  | CLAIMS | claims@mail.ru
 34 |                  | CLAIMS | claims@mail.ru
(6 rows)
```

Comment: Покажите что и как вы делаете

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець, дополнил свой пост.

Comment: Нужен такой метод в `Organization`: `public void addEmail(OrganizationEmail email) { emails.add(email); email.setOrganization(this); }` Я думаю идею Вы поняли.